# Fatal error in Library 'require' and 'use' PHP

Tags: php, github, smtp

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email for email validation, but I have a problem in the sintallation of the package (manually, I'm not using composer)

So here is the hierarchy of my files:

[image]

My index has this code:

```
<?php

require 'Library/Validator.php';

use \Library\Validator;

$email     = 'someone@example.org';
$sender    = 'sender@example.org';
$validator = new Validator($email, $sender);

$results   = $validator->validate();

var_dump($results);

$log = $validator->getLog();
var_dump($log);

?>
```

And the 'Validator.php' has 1000 lines of code but here are the first 25 lines so you can have an idea:

```
<?php

namespace SMTPValidateEmail;

use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\Exception as Exception;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\Timeout as TimeoutException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\NoTimeout as NoTimeoutException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\NoConnection as NoConnectionException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\UnexpectedResponse as UnexpectedResponseException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\NoHelo as NoHeloException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\NoMailFrom as NoMailFromException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\NoResponse as NoResponseException;
use \SMTPValidateEmail\Exceptions\SendFailed as SendFailedException;

class Validator
{

    public $log = [];

    /**
     * Print stuff as it happens or not
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $debug = false;
```

So, the output of the 'index.php' is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Library\Validator" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmailValidation\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmailValidation\index.php on line 9
```

Comment: It looks it wants to use composers autoloader.

Comment: Your `Validator`-class is under the namespace `SMTPValidateEmail`, not `Library`. So it should be `use SMTPValidateEmail\Validator`

Answer (score 0):

use namespace name and class name to call it.

use \SMTPValidateEmail\Validator;

example
namespace Helpers
and the CheckUser class

then the text becomes

use Helpers/CheckUser;